# Stick window pop-up to it's position

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I've created a window pop-up that appears when clicking a button. If it matters, the content window shows a video. Now, the problem is that when the window is shown/loaded I can still scroll. Now, I'm thinking it about keeping it this way, since the code is written so you can click anywhere else on the website and then the Window pop-up dissapears. However, the issue is that the pop-up follows along when I scroll. How can I make the pop-up stick to it's position?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  
<style>


  /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80%; 
  height: 60%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
   width: 70%;
        height: 80%;
        position: fixed; /*Can also be `fixed`*/
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        /*Solves a problem in which the content is being cut when the div is smaller than its' wrapper:*/
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
  background-color: #0E0E0E;
  
  
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
 
  
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: -1px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
.video{
           width: 65%;
        height: 65%;
        position: absolute; /*Can also be `fixed`*/
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        /*Solves a problem in which the content is being cut when the div is smaller than its' wrapper:*/
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
 
}
.myBtn{
  margin-top: 20%;

}
</style>
</head>
        <body>   
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <center>
    <div class="video">
        
    <video src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/1ef399dd4bb345e485f6e4784a9d0031.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay width="100%" height="100%"></video>
</center>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
   
 

          </body> 
            <script>
              // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
            </script>


  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`fixed` positioning means that it is fixed to the viewport, doesn't matter where you scroll it stays there, you can use `absolute` positioning which 'fixes' it relative to the document body (unless specified otherwise). You can read more about positioning [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: I have positioned fixed already in both my Modal & the Modal-content

Comment: Yes what I'm saying is it should be position: absolute, not position: fixed.